# How to schedule tasks with a delay

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to schedule a task to run after 2 minutes. Then when the time is up I need to check if we are still `ONLINE`. If we are still online I simple don't do anything. If `OFFLINE` then I will do some work.

```
private synchronized void schedule(ConnectionObj connectionObj)
{
    if(connectionObj.getState() == ONLINE)
    {
        // schedule timer
    }
    else
    {
       // cancel task.
    }
}
```

This is the code I am considering:

```
@Async
private synchronized void task(ConnectionObj connectionObj)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000); // short time for test
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(connectionObj.getState() == ONLINE)
    {
       // don't do anything
    }

    else
    {
       doWork();
    }
}
```

---

For scheduling this task should I use @Async? I may still get many more calls to schedule while I am waiting inside the `task()` method.

Does SpringBoot have something like a thread that I create each time `schedule()` gets called so that this becomes easy?

I am looking for something similar to a `postDelay()` from Android: [how to use postDelayed() correctly in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379301/how-to-use-postdelayed-correctly-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about an exclusively `spring-boot` solution, since it isn't something that I work with.

However, you can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), which is in the base Java environment. For your usage, it would look something like this:

```
@Async
private synchronized void task(ConnectionObj connectionObj)
{
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(() -> {
        if(connectionObj.getState() == ONLINE) 
        {
            // don't do anything
        } 

        else 
        {
           doWork();
        }
    }, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

I used lambda expressions, which are explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/).

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Seeing as how you need to schedule them "on-demand", @Scheduling won't help as you mentioned. I think the simplest solution is to go for something like @Leftist proposed.

Otherwise, as I mentioned in the comments, you can look at Spring Boot Quartz integration to create a job and schedule it with Quartz. It will then take care of running it after the two minute mark. It's just more code for almost the same result.

**Original**

For Spring Boot, you can use the built in [Scheduling support](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks). It will take care of running your code on time on a separate thread.

As the article states, you must enable scheduling with `@EnableScheduling`.

Then you annotate your method you want to run with `@Scheduled(..)` and you can either setup a fixedDelay or cron expression, or any of the other timing options to suit your time execution requirements.

Comment: I need to control when to start it though. I believe `@Scheduled` cannot be told to start or stop.

Comment: @J_Strauton. Ah, so you mean you need to schedule it "on-demand" and then have the thread kick off after two minutes?

Comment: Got it. My bad, didn't catch that requirement. You can look into Spring Boot Quartz  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule but it's a bit heavier weight than what you might be looking for. A simple solution would be to use the solution proposed by @Leftist.