# How to display different image after another with Glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I want to display an other image after a delay. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("e");
    test.add("a");
    if (test.get(0) == "e") {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://something.something/something.jpg")
                .into(imageView);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (test.get(1) == "a") {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("https://something.something/something2.jpg")
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
}
```

But only the 2nd image apppears if i do that. Any solution?

Comment: You are loading a different image in the same image view, and thus the image will be overwritten, is this your intended behaviour?

Comment: yes, but I want to have a little delay so I can see both pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new method

```
private void loadImage(String imageLink){
    Glide.with(this).load(imageLink).into(imageView);
}
```

now simply call this where you want to load first image and second image in the same imageView

```
loadImage("imageLink");

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something after 3sec
        loadImage("next ImageLink");
    }
}, 3000);
```

Something like this, you can also modify loadImage method so it can also accept ImageView as a parameter if you want to load images in different ImageView with delay

```
if (test.get(0) == "e") {
    loadImage("https://something.something/something.jpg");
}
if (test.get(1) == "a") {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 3sec (3000 = 3 sec)
            loadImage("https://something.something/something2.jpg");
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Hope this will help!

## Edit 1:

if you want to load both pics with delay use

```
if (test.get(0) == "e") {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 3sec (3000 = 3 sec)
            loadImage("https://something.something/something.jpg"); // image 1 
        }
    }, 3000);
}
if (test.get(1) == "a") {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 3sec (3000 = 3 sec)
            loadImage("https://something.something/something2.jpg"); // image 2
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Welcome, please accept my answer and also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . your question lacked some information.

Comment: I want to ask something, how do I add delay to the first condition too?

Comment: add `Handler` to the first `if` also

Comment: check updated answer, and starting thinking and doing stuff yourself, also please at least try and if you are trying, **try harder** . if you tried same code but it is not working tell me

Comment: That is exactly what i did. But still only the 2nd picture shows up. It works if i change the delay of the first picture to lower than 3 seconds, but if i do that, the array cant work dynamically

Comment: sorry, you have to create 1 handler and call `postDelayed()` inside it, also you need to check `if` statement inside it, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379301/how-to-use-postdelayed-correctly-in-android-studio) to learn `postDelayed()`

Comment: tried the one on the link, the problem still occurs. Also what do you mean by 'check the if statement inside it'?

Comment: set `picture_url` and call `handler`. show image inside `handler` and at the bottom of handler update `picture_url` and call `postDelayed` so it will call the handler again. add some checker so it will not become `infinite loop`